# Access Uploaded Document's Original Creation Date in SP2010

Tags: file-upload, date-time

I've spent some time searching this site and others but haven't seen a conclusive answer to this question: is there a non-code way to display the original creation date for an Office document in a SharePoint 2010 library?  Our environment does not allow for custom code solutions, so we're a bit limited on the approach.  I want to avoid manual entry and cannot expect users to care enough to open the file and then know to open the properties.  This needs to be something visible in a library column.

For example, if I create a Word document on 1 May 2013 and then decide to upload the file on 1 July 2013, I'd like a column to show 1 May 2013.  Currently the only auto-tracking creation date column of which I'm aware is **Created**, which shows the upload date (1 July) and not the original file creation date.  It *seems* this should be possible since the original creation date is a property of the Word document, but so far nothing seems to indicate how to expose that to the library.

Additionally, is there a way to do the same for non-Office files such as PDFs, images, and emails?  Office documents are the near-term focus, but being able to locate dates on other types would be helpful as well.  (Even if the first bit is able to be done without custom work, I expect this one will need it.)

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 3):

Not possible without code.  The creation date in sharepoint its the creation date of the item in the library, not from the document.

Udpate:  I asked my colleagues and:  Sharepoint search extracts metadata properties from the documents, and with the search you can show to the users the creation date.  However you need to modify the XSLT  that transforms the results XML into HTML. Something can be done, but not an easy solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Luis.  I'll keep looking, and if I can figure something out I'll see about a wiki entry.

Comment: Did anyone have any success with this? The only thing I can find is a PowerShell script that opens the documents one by one to grab the Content Created date. It's a very slow solution.