# How to capture original creation date of a document while uploading into document library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, date-time

I am uploading a document in SharePoint document library and would like to capture original creation date of the document. Can anyone let me know about this?

For Eg: If a document is created on 1st of July and I am uploading it on 15th of July. Then I would like to capture the 1st July in some column. I can create a new column in the library to add the date.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`SPFile.Properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.properties) to read the properties of the uploaded file. In the aforementioned link the example outputs a property `vti_timecreated`. You would have to create an event receiver to check when the file is uploaded to library and get the created value and put it into a new column. Alternatively, you can also create a timer job to do this to run say, every hour, and update the library.

Comment: This only gives the item time creation instead of file creation.

Comment: @Ankit: The documentation for [`vti_timecreated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd589236(v=office.11).aspx) says - its the time, including date, at which the current object was created. I would assume that it would be the creation of the file, though I haven't tried it so cannot verify it. Also refer to [this question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/66285/20540) which says that - Not possible without code. I would say that your best chance in getting your value would be somewhere in [`SPFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile)

Comment: This works when you are uploading the document from same server. But doesn't working from client machine. I tried this earlier as well.